# How can i solve hits issue with icons in bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, icons, font-awesome

I have two pages with bootstrap table on it and the icons display in different way.
[The right way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSG7q.png)

[Teh wrong way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi57M.png)

What can I do?

Comment: Without any of your code, it’s not possible to see what’s happening on your two pages. Can you add enough code so the problem can be [reproduced](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag "html" needs "**!DOCTYPE** html" to solve the problem.